# Why is const variable localQuotes not defined in this random quotes generator?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, uncaught-reference-error

**Problem explained more clearly here:**
I am creating a simple random quote generator using JavaScript. I have hundreds of quotes in an array in a file called "quotes.js" and then the actual function to make it work in a file called "script.js" which are both linked to an "index.html" page. I'm getting the error in my "script.js" page which is supposed to allow a random quote get fetched from the array in quotes.js and display that random quote on the screen with each refresh of the page (you would see the quote in the console and not the actual page yet). Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error and how to define the variable localQuotes?

**This is the error I get in the Developers Tools Console tab in Chrome:**

[image]

> Uncaught ReferenceError: localQuotes is not defined
> at newQuote (script.js:3)
> at script.js:7 newQuote @ script.js:3 (anonymous) @ script.js:7

**Here is my code from script.js:**

```js
function newQuote() {
    const quote = localQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * localQuotes.length)];
    console.log(quote); 
}

newQuote();
```

**Here is a shorter version of the array in quotes.js:**

```js
 const localQuotes = [
 {
    text: 'The greatest remedy for anger is delay.',
    author: 'Seneca',
  },
  {
    text: 'Growth itself contains the germ of happiness.',
    author: 'Pearl Buck',
  },
  {
    text: "You can do what's reasonable or you can decide what's possible.",
    author: null,
  },
];
```

**And then finally my linked JavaScript in the html file:**

```html
<!-- Script -->
    <script>src="quotes.js"</script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was in the html  tags.

Instead of:

```html
<script>src="quotes.js"</script>
<script>src="script.js"</script>
```

It needs to be:

```html
<script src="quotes.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes.js will need to give global access to the variable for it to work. This is how you should do it:

```
window.localQuotes = {...}
```

Oh and your script tag is wrong, you have a typo there, I expected it to be a typo when writing the question so if it still doesn't work, fix that typo.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript and programming in general. Can you explain in a little more detail? What goes into the {. . .}? And does it go at the end of the array or the beginning? I thought that "window" had to do with displaying it on the screen. I just need it to be displayed in the console tab. Sorry if I'm completely off base here, I'm very much new to this.

Comment: The ... represents your quotes object. So you only need to replace `const localQuotes` with `window.localQuotes` - this is because script.js does not have access to the variables inside of quotes.js, but you can share variables by adding them to the global window object.

Comment: Nice catch on the typo! Thank you

Comment: Well the errors are gone but now nothing is displaying in the Console tab. Any ideas? I changed the code to this: 

window.localQuotes = [
{
text: 'Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.',
author: 'Yogi Berra',
},
];

Comment: I get this error when I hover over window.localQuotes in the editor:

Property 'localQuotes' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)